# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' error finding elements within DOM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, attributeerror

I tryed find element into tree DOM but I have a problem. I wrote:

```
age = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ads']/ul/li[6]/span[2]").text
```

But all the time it display my the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

What is wrong?

Comment: Error seems self-explanatory. Did you mean `find_element` rather than `find_elements`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`find_elements*` returns a *list* where is *`text`* is an attribute of a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139).

---

### Solution

Instead of `find_elements_by_xpath()` you need to use `find_element_by_xpath()`. Effectively your line of code will be:

```
age = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ads']/ul/li[6]/span[2]").text
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is just one element that you wanna get the text from use `find_element` instead of `find_elements`

```
age = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ads']/ul/li[6]/span[2]").text
```

`find_elements` will give you a `list` of elements, to get the text of each element you have to loop over the result:

```
for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ads']/ul/li[6]/span[2]"):
    element.text
```